# Windows Task Manager Set priority Access is denied

Tags: windows, permissions, task-manager

I'm trying to change the process priority for a video game, but it gives me an "Access is denied" exception. Same for changing it's affinity, which would be fine too, but not 100% my current goal.

Task Manager is running as administrator, I have Security Permissions for the executable file, I'm not sure what else I need, or why it's even possible to prevent an administrator from changing something like this.

Note: I specifically want to change the priority as the process is running, not prior to starting the process.

(I'm using Windows 10, if it matters.)